# Map : $f,g : X\to S^{2n+1}$ are continuous but not homotopic, show that there exist $x^\ast\in X$ such that $f(x^\ast) = g(x^\ast)$.

Tags: general-topology

The problem is shown as title, and so far I've just learned things like homotopic and fundamental group. Does it need knowledge like homology group ... ?

I had Google about things like "Degree", but it seems like only works when map: $S^n \to S^n$. So I get stuck and don't know where to go. (I have totally no idea how to work with the space $S^{2n+1}$ !)

So anything helpful would be appreciated!

Comment: Is X any topological space or are there any restrictions like being a CW complex?

Comment: @Noel Lundström Thank you Noel, according to the problem, there is no restriction for space $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the opposite. Using a convex combination, you can show that $f$ and $-g$ are homotopic. By viewing $S^{2n+1}$ as the unit sphere of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, you can show that $-1$ and the identity are homotopic (the homotopy being multiplication by $e^{it\pi}$), so that $-g$ and $g$ are homotopic, thus $f,g$ homotopic.

Comment: Nice! It's some lemma i've proved before but i've no idea how to use it. Thank you Mindlack.